# Validate Dynamically Added Input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have used [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) jquery validation plugin for the following form.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#commentForm").validate();
    });

    function addInput() {
        var obj = document.getElementById("list").cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(obj);
    }
</script>

<form id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <p id="parent">
        <input id="list"  class="required" />
    </p>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="button" value="add" onClick="addInput()" />
</form>
```

When the add button is clicked a new input is dynamically added. However when the form is submitted only the first input field is validated. How can i validate dynamically added inputs? 
Thank you...

Comment: have you tried `$('form').on('submit', function(e){$(this).validate();return false;});`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26542591/5557983 This solution by @Stephen Muecke worked for me

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should have 'name' attribute for your inputs. You need to add the rules dynamically, one option is to add them when the form submits.

And here is my solution that I've tested and it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var numberIncr = 1; // used to increment the name for the inputs

        function addInput() {
            $('#inputs').append($('<input class="comment" name="name'+numberIncr+'" />'));
            numberIncr++;
        }

        $('form.commentForm').on('submit', function(event) {

            // adding rules for inputs with class 'comment'
            $('input.comment').each(function() {
                $(this).rules("add", 
                    {
                        required: true
                    })
            });            

            // prevent default submit action         
            event.preventDefault();

            // test if form is valid 
            if($('form.commentForm').validate().form()) {
                console.log("validates");
            } else {
                console.log("does not validate");
            }
        })

        // set handler for addInput button click
        $("#addInput").on('click', addInput);

        // initialize the validator
        $('form.commentForm').validate();

   });


</script>
```

And the html form part:

```
<form class="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <div>

        <p id="inputs">    
            <input class="comment" name="name0" />
        </p>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="button" value="add" id="addInput" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Good luck! Please approve answer if it suits you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort @Angel. It worked like magic. Awesome work :)

Comment: FWIW, you could just call validate once on document.ready, and then do your rules adding within the `addInput` function.  If you want to show that validation is succeeding/failing, attach handlers to `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler`.

Comment: Yes, that might work, you need to add the rule for the last added input, like $('input.comment:last').rules('add', {});  But I find it more straight forward to have all the validation parts in the same place.

Comment: +1 for the answer for dynamic fields. I did it up front with addInput, to get the immediate blur validation, rather than waiting for submit.

Comment: Huge gotcha that about drove me crazy... dynamic fields must have the `name` attribute or validation won't work. Thanks, @Angel, for your answer.

Comment: `required="true"`  is what I am looking for, it solved the dynamic field disappearing on client side validation. How to show a custom message for each dynamic field?

Comment: Needs to include calling the function below created by @RitchieD whenever the form is not valid. See my comment on his post for a bit more info on my usage.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536271/validate-dynamically-added-input-fields#answer-33527919

Comment: thank you. rules(add) is the best solution so far https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

Comment: can anyone know after validation how to access post data in the process.php page?

Comment: I had case where there were multiple dynamic table rows with duplicate fields. Your tip worked for me too.

Comment: Worked perfect here!

Answer (score 51):

Reset form validation after adding new fields.

```
function resetFormValidator(formId) {
    $(formId).removeData('validator');
    $(formId).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(formId);
}
```

Comment: This solution is much better

Comment: from where this function needs to be called ? in on submit of the form, or the javascript method which adds new field ?

Comment: when I am using this I am getting this error :`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined`

Comment: You would normally call this function in the add new field function after the field has been added.  This way it will find the new field.   Not sure about the error.  Something missing somewhere....

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I have been looking all over, and thought I could get away with just parsing the form again, but obviousley I need to remove the validator first! Thank you once again!

Comment: Allows the validation plugin to use data attributes present in the control for list of validations to be performed on that control. Thanks...

Comment: LIFE SAVER! Validate was only looking at the dynamic fields after the first click. Now with this function being called whenever the form is not valid, it is reset so new dynamically added fields will be recognized. Thank you so much for this post!

Comment: @theordinarygeek, You would normally call this function in the add new field function after the field has been added.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek, unfortunately I can't see the issue.  Something else missing like jquery validation.  Or different versions?  Sorry I can't be of more help.   But for sure this methods works, I use it a lot.

Comment: @HappyCoder add this script https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validation-unobtrusive

Comment: if using dynamically generated HTML fields, this is the solution. - for that sir you get an up vote :)

Comment: can any one share the demo?

Answer (score 6):

You need to re-parse the form after adding dynamic content in order to validate the content

```
$('form').data('validator', null);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```

Answer (score 4):

The one mahesh posted is not working because the attribute name is missing:

So instead of

```
<input id="list" class="required"  />
```

You can use:

```
<input id="list" name="list" class="required"  />
```

[Modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/bAsat/43/)

Answer (score 4):

jquery validation plugin version work fine **v1.15.0** but **v1.17.0** not work for me.

```
$(document).find('#add_patient_form').validate({
          ignore: [],
          rules:{
            'email[]':
            {
              required:true,
            },               
          },
          messages:{
            'email[]':
            {
              'required':'Required'
            },            
          },    
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

In regards to @RitchieD response, here is a jQuery plugin version to make things easier if you are using jQuery.

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.initValidation = function () {

        $(this).removeData("validator");
        $(this).removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(this);

        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

This can be used like this:

```
$("#SomeForm").initValidation();
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a form you can add a class name as such:

```
<form id="my-form">
  <input class="js-input" type="text" name="samplename" />
  <input class="js-input" type="text" name="samplename" />
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

you can then use the [addClassRules](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) method of validator to add your rules like this and this will apply to all the dynamically added inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addClassRules('js-input', {
    required: true,
  });
  //validate the form
  $('#my-form').validate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form-btn').click(function () {
//set global rules & messages array to use in validator
   var rules = {};
   var messages = {};
//get input, select, textarea of form
   $('#formId').find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      rules[name] = {};
      messages[name] = {};

      rules[name] = {required: true}; // set required true against every name
//apply more rules, you can also apply custom rules & messages
      if (name === "email") {
         rules[name].email = true;
         //messages[name].email = "Please provide valid email";
      }
      else if(name==='url'){
        rules[name].required = false; // url filed is not required
//add other rules & messages
      }
   });
//submit form and use above created global rules & messages array
   $('#formId').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }).validate({
            rules: rules,
            messages: messages,
            submitHandler: function (form) {
            console.log("validation success");
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. I like this approach because instead of re initializing the form validator he just waits till the user tries to submit then adds the rules in the each() and initializes the form validator with all the dynamically generated rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try using input arrays:

```
<form action="try.php" method="post">
    <div id="events_wrapper">
        <div id="sub_events">
            <input type="text" name="firstname[]" />                                       
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add_another_event" name="add_another_event" value="Add Another" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and add this script and [jQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js), using foreach() to retrieve the data being $_POST'ed:

```
<script>                                                                                    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add_another_event").click(function(){
        var $address = $('#sub_events');
        var num = $('.clonedAddress').length; // there are 5 children inside each address so the prevCloned address * 5 + original
        var newNum = num + 1;
        var newElem = $address.clone().attr('id', 'address' + newNum).addClass('clonedAddress');

        //set all div id's and the input id's
        newElem.children('div').each (function (i) {
            this.id = 'input' + (newNum*5 + i);
        });

        newElem.find('input').each (function () {
            this.id = this.id + newNum;
            this.name = this.name + newNum;
        });

        if (num > 0) {
            $('.clonedAddress:last').after(newElem);
        } else {
            $address.after(newElem);
        }

        $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

        $("#remove").click(function(){

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#commentForm").validate();
    });

    function addInput() {

        var indexVal = $("#index").val();
        var index = parseInt(indexVal) + 1
        var obj = '<input id="list'+index+'" name=list['+index+']  class="required" />'
        $("#parent").append(obj);

        $("#list"+index).rules("add", "required");
        $("#index").val(index)
    }
</script>

<form id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="index" name="list[1]" id="index" value="1">
    <p id="parent">
        <input id="list1"  class="required" />
    </p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="button" value="add" onClick="addInput()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your solution so it is not just code?