# Validate dynamically added fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm adding a table row with jQuery on button click:

```
$("#add_row").click(function () {
        zeile++;
        $("#ArtikelTabelle > tbody").append('<tr id="reihe' + zeile + '">' +
        '<td rowspan="2"><b>' + (zeile + 1) + '</b></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control" id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccArtikelNr" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccArtikelNr" type="text"  /></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control" id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccWarentarifNr" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccWarentarifNr" type="text" /></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="Das Feld &quot;Anzahl&quot; muss eine Zahl sein." data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Anzahl&quot; ist erforderlich." id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccAnzahl" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccAnzahl" type="text" /></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="Das Feld &quot;Einzelpreis&quot; muss eine Zahl sein." data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Einzelpreis&quot; ist erforderlich." id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccEinzelpreis" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccEinzelpreis" type="text" /></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="Das Feld &quot;Gesamtpreis&quot; muss eine Zahl sein." data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Gesamtpreis&quot; ist erforderlich." id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccGesamtpreis" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccGesamtpreis" type="text" /></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="Das Feld &quot;Anzahl Pakete&quot; muss eine Zahl sein." data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Anzahl Pakete&quot; ist erforderlich." id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccAnzahlPakete" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccAnzahlPakete" type="text" /></td>' +
        '<td><input class="checkbox-inline" data-val="true" data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Fertig verpackt?&quot; ist erforderlich." id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccFertigVerpackt" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccFertigVerpackt" type="checkbox" /><input name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccFertigVerpackt" type="hidden" /></td>' +
        '<td rowspan="2"><a class="btn btn-default delete_row" data-rowid="' + zeile + '">Artikel löschen</a></td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr id="text' + zeile + '">' +
        '<td colspan="3"> <textarea class="form-control input-md" id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccInhaltsbeschreibung" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccInhaltsbeschreibung" placeholder="Inhaltsbeschreibung"></textarea> </td>' +
        '<td colspan="4"> <textarea class="form-control input-md" id="ccTabelle_' + zeile + '__ccBemerkungInhalt" name="ccTabelle[' + zeile + '].ccBemerkungInhalt" placeholder="Bemerkungen"></textarea> </td>' +
    '</tr>');

        aktualisiereZeilennummer();

    });
```

I also use this content to initially create a row.

But on clicking button submit I want to validate these fields if they are filled or not an highlight those fields.

I tried using `$("#form").validate();` but I don't really know how to use it and it didn't work.

Also the validation in my model failed:

```
    public class InhaltModel
{
    //Inhalt
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Artikelnummer")]
    public string ccArtikelNr { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Warentarif-Nr")]
    public string ccWarentarifNr { get; set; }
}
```

If I use Razor to add a row it works but not with jQuery, but i need it dynamic so that I can add as many rows as I want to.

Can anyone tell me how to validate my fields ?

Comment: If you don't know how `validate()` works, read its docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to parse the `form` again after adding dynamic content in order for that content to be validated

```
$('form').data('validator', null);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```

Comment: I tested with this and it works perfectly fine now. Thank you :).

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly. Same as I wanted.

Comment: can you guys elaborate a little. Do we need to call the validate() method after adding this code ?

Comment: @HappyCoder. No, that is done automatically when you submit the form (or tab out of a form control that has been previously validated)

Comment: @Rusty Seeing how jQuery Validation is a plugin to jQuery - most likely no.