# validation fails when not using an input property/tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code that contains validation:

```
<div id="ContactDialog" style="display: none;">

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.subject)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.subject, new { @class = "AboutControls" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subject)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.from)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.from, new { @class = "AboutControls" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.from)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.body)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.body, new { @class = "AboutControls" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.body)
    <hr />
    <br /><br />   
</div>
```

This code is executed from JQuery ajax code. Because of this, the validation is not triggered. All the fields are required, but since they are not called through an `<input type="submit" value="..." />` the validation is not triggered, and they will go through even when they are null, resulting in an exception. How can I make sure the validation is triggered even when no using an `<input ... />`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use ASP.NET MVC validation with jquery ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005773/use-asp-net-mvc-validation-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Are these controls inside a `<form>` element (which is necessary for the `data-val-*` attributes to be rendered and used in conjuction with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`)

Comment: Yes they are in a BeginForm

Comment: Then in that case, you must not have the relevant jquery files included (or your creating the form dynamically in which case you need to re-parse the validator)

Comment: Yes I am creating the form dynamically. How can I re-parse the validator?
I have tried including: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script> manually at the bottom of the page that creates the form. Normally these 2 tags are also found in the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: @user1960836, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542509/validate-dynamically-added-fields/26542591#26542591) shows how to reparse the validator, although it looks like you could just include the form in the view initially (inside a hidden element)