# Add row in table with jquery which is connected with model in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this table and shows values from the server.
How I can with jquery add a new row in this table if I want to send values from the table to the Server

```
<table id="Products" class="Products">
    <tr>
        <th>ProductId</th>
        <th>Productname</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>UnitPrice</th>
    </tr>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.NorthOrderDetails.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductName)
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductID)</td>

            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductName)</td>

            <td><input type="hidden" name="NorthOrderDetails.Index" value="@i" /> </td>

            <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].Quantity) </td>

            <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].UnitPrice, String.Format("{0}", Model.NorthOrderDetails[i].UnitPrice))</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="delete" data-id="@Model.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductID">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I previously gave you [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) showing 2 possible methods. What do you not understand?

Comment: @StephenMuecke

Need I use javascript to dynamically create indexed inputs for post back?

Comment: You could post back the form, save everything, redirect to the GET method, add a new item to the collection and recreate the view all over again, but you will get far better performance if you use javascript to add the element to the DOM.

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Ok. I understand. I want to use jquery for this purpose, but is there more nice method for it than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542509/validate-dynamically-added-fields/26542591#26542591)

Comment: Look at option 1 in link in my first comment. Using ajax to call a method that returns a partial in conjunction with BeginCollectionItem is as easy as it gets (and it means you can simply your main view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  and if I use BeginCollectionItem, Can I add new row in empty table using ajax to call a method that returns me some data for displaying?

Comment: Yes. The partial just need to be based on the `NorthOrderDetails` class.

Comment: @StephenMuecke But I use NorthOrder' class in this view. And this class contains collection of NorthOrderDetails. Can I use and NortOrder, and NorthOrderDetails classes for one view?

Comment: The main view uses `NorthOrder` but the partial uses `NorthOrderDetails`. Have a look at the link in my first comment and try it out. If you still having problems understanding, I will post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I use BeginCollectionItem. I will wait your answer which u want to write

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [BeginCollectionItem](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) html helper a partial view for your model to generate collection items with unique indexers and allow binding to the collection on post back. Note you have not indicate the type of property `NorthOrderDetails`, but form your previous questions, I assume its `NorthOrderDetails.cs`

Create a partial for `NorthOrderDetails.cs`

`Views/YourController/_NorthOrderDetails.cshtml`

```cs
@model NorthOrderDetailscs
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem()) 
{
  <tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductName)
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductID)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductName)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UnitPrice)</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="delete" data-id="@Model.ProductID">Delete</button>
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductID)
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductName)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Side notes:

1. Do not include the hidden input for the `Index`
2. An `<input>` is not a valid child of a `<tr>` element (place the hidden inputs inside a `<td>` element
3. `String.Format("{0}", Model.NorthOrderDetails[i].UnitPrice` does
   absolutely nothing (If you wanted to to format it as (say) currency, then
   it would be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UnitPrice. "{0:C}")`)

You can now remove the `for` loop in the main view and replace with

```html
<table id="Products" class="Products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ProductId</th>
      <th>Productname</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>UnitPrice</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model.NorthOrderDetails)
    {
      @Html.Partial("_NorthOrderDetails", item)
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This will generate a bit of extra html (the indexers for the existing items are a `Guid` rather than an `int`) but it means you only have one place to maintain your code.

Then in the main view, add the following script for your 'Add' button

```html
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
```

```js
<script>
  var tableBody = $('#Products tbody');
  var url = '@Url.Action("Add", "YourControllerName")'; // adjust to suit
  $('#add').click(function() {
    $.get('url, function(response) {
      tableBody.append(response);
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the controller method

```cs
public PartialViewResult Add()
{
  var model = new NorthOrderDetailscs();
  return PartialView("_NorthOrderDetails");
}
```

Finally, if you are using client side validation (jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js), and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` with your properties, then you need re-parse the validator each time you add new elements to the DOM as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542509/validate-dynamically-added-fields/26542591#26542591).

Comment: Some problems appeared. unfortunately

Comment: +1 Thanks - this helped immensely for a project I'm working on. A few snags I run into: 1) I had to change `Html.BeginCollectionItem()` to `Html.BeginCollectionItem("PropertyNameOfList")`. 2) Appending directly to the `tableBody` as you have done dropped the `tr` wrapper. I had to use a variant of `$('<tr />').html(response).appendTo(tableBody);` to get this rendering as expected.