# Client doesn't make a connection to the SignalR server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm trying to implement SignalR into my application. To start things of I just started with something very basic, but for some reason I'm getting an error the whole time. Pease could you have a look at my code and see where I'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Starup Code

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(CdvPortal.Startup))]
namespace CdvPortal
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Hub Code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace CdvPortal.Hubs
{

    public class ReservationsHub : Hub
    {
        public void NewReservations()
        {
            Clients.All.NewReservation("hey this works");
        }
    }
}
```

Client side code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
        @*<script src="~/Signalr/hubs"></script>*@
        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function () {
                var connection = $.hubConnection();
                var hub = connection.createHubProxy('reservationsHub')
                hub.on('NewReservation', function (message) {
                    alert(message);
                });

                connection.start().done(function(){
                    hub.invoke('NewReservations')
                });                    
            }());
```

[image: Error I'm getting]

Comment: The hub name is case sensitive, should be ReservationsHub not reservationsHub.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fals, I tried it. It still doesn't work. Also on the tutorial on asp.net I saw that they made the first letter of the hub class a small capital on the client side, not sure why but that is why I did it. Is there perhaps something else I can try?

Comment: Why is this line `@*<script src="~/Signalr/hubs"></script>*@` commented?

Comment: @Przno , because I've been through several tutorials, some of them showed I should reference that script and some didn't showed it. Should I reference it?

Comment: I believe you do need that line @przno point to since its a [dynamically generated proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client).

Comment: @Fals , could you possible have a look at this question, I urgently need to finish an app and I got stuck there. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30261087/4832762,  I would really appreciate it. Thanks