# Knockout.js not wanting to bind my list of records that has been grouped by location

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, linq-to-entities

I have been trying for a few days now with no luck. I'm building a ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I'm building a reservations application for a restaurant. The idea is to extract a days reservations group it by location with linq to entities and then send it with signalR to the client side. On the client side I want to bind this grouped query with knockout.js and then display it, and that is where everything goes wrong. Sending the grouped reservations to the client side works fine but I can't seem to make the mapping with knockout work. Please help.

Model on Server Side

```
var Reservations = db.BistroReservations_Reservations
                                       .GroupBy(reservation => reservation.BistroReservations_Location.Description)
                                       .OrderBy(reservation => reservation.Key.ToString()).ToList();


var context = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ReservationsHub>();
        context.Clients.All.TestingGroupedReservations(Reservations);
```

Model on Client Side

```
var ReservationsViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

var connection = $.hubConnection();
    var hub = connection.createHubProxy('reservationsHub') 

     var GroupedReservations = ko.mapping.fromJS(reservations);
//Testing -map a collection object to a observalbe and display it underneath the webpage
    hub.on('TestingGroupedReservations', function (reservation) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(reservation, GroupedReservations);
    });
```

}

```
ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Code on the client view side

```
  <table class="table" data-bind="visible: !loading()">
                <thead class=".h1 glyphicon-bold">Reservations of Selected Day</thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: GroupedReservations">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Shift</td>
                        <td>
                            <table data-bind="foreach:$data">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td data-bind="text:BistroReservations_GuestID"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.GroupedReservations = ko.mapping.fromJS(reservations);
```

Where is the declaration of "reservations" variable in this line:

```
var GroupedReservations = ko.mapping.fromJS(reservations);
```

Comment: your code example isn't a full answer, OP never returned the self variable. Without returning that VAR nothing would have access to GroupedReservations

Comment: @ArtDumez , thank you for your answer. The "reservations" object is the object I received from the server via SignalR, but I'm trying to do is then to map it to the "GroupReservations" object, but you are right I think that is where the problem is because I'm getting a unhandled exception saying "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'reservations' is undefined", but I have no idea how to define it. Do you perhaps have a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From first blush you are never setting the GroupedReservations property and you are also not returning self. If you do not `return self` all of your properties are considered private.

In addition anything you want to be publicly accessible needs to be a property on `self`.

```
var ReservationsViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

var connection = $.hubConnection();
    var hub = connection.createHubProxy('reservationsHub') 

         **self.GroupedReservations  = ko.mapping.fromJS(reservations);**
//Testing -map a collection object to a observalbe and display it underneath the webpage
    hub.on('TestingGroupedReservations', function (reservation) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(reservation, GroupedReservations);
    });
**return self;**
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes but as mentioned in the comment above, I still get the error "reservations is undefined". Do you perhaps have an idea on how I could define it?