# Remote validation doesn't work when property to validate is inside a modal Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, bootstrap-modal, remote-validation

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3.
When an user create an account, I need the chosen nickname be unique, so I use the `Remote` DataAnnotation like this :

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("CheckNickname", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "This nickname is already used")]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

I used it in a strongly-typed view, via `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nickname)` and it **perfeclty works**.

However, I created another model with the exact same property.

```
public class MyOtherModel
{
    // ...

    [Required]
    [Remote("CheckNickname", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "This nickname is already used")]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

I used this MyOtherModel.Nickname on a strongly-typed view via :
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyOtherModel.Nickname)`
However, in this case only, the data passed to my `CheckNickame()` method is always `null`.

There are only two differences :

- In the second case, the property I want to remotely validate is contained in another model (is it a problem ? I don't think so...)
- In the second case, the property is displayed **inside** a [modal bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) (is it a problem ?)

For information, this is what my `CheckNickname()` looks like :

```
public JsonResult CheckNickname(string nickname)
{
    UserDAL userDAL = new UserDAL();
    bool userIsAvailable = !userDAL.IsUserAlreadyInUse(nickname);

    return Json(userIsAvailable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As I wrote it before, in the second case only, the parameter `nickname` is always `null` whereas it works as expected in the first case.

Is anyone knows why ?
Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE :**
I created this method :

```
public JsonResult CheckNickname2([Bind(Prefix = "MyOtherModel")]string nickname)
{
    UserDAL userDAL = new UserDAL();
    bool userIsAvailable = !userDAL.IsUserAlreadyInUse(nickname);

    return Json(userIsAvailable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The call is now :
http://mysite/Validation/CheckNickname2?MyOtherModel.Nickname=Alex
but if I put a breakpoint on `CheckNickname2`, the `nickname` paremeter is still `null` !

However, the call on the working validaton method is :
http://mysite/Validation/CheckNickname?Nickname=Alex
and this one works...

---

**SOLUTION:**
Ok, solved by changing `[Bind(Prefix = "MyOtherModel")]` to `[Bind(Prefix = "MyOtherModel.Nickname")]` as suggested by [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916684/1866810)

Comment: are you calling that view that need to show inside the modal using jquery (at runtime) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, the html generated will be `name="MyOtherModel.Nickname"` so the key/value pair posted back will be `MyOtherModel.Nickname:yourValue`. Change the controller method to

```
public JsonResult CheckNickname([Bind(Prefix="MyOtherModel.Nickname")]string nickname)
```

which will effectively strip the prefix and bind correctly to parameter `nickname`

Note also that the `modal` usage may be a problem if this is adding dynamic content after the initial page has been rendered (in which case you need to re-parse the validator)

Comment: You're right about the html generated, which is `name="MyOtherModel.Nickname"`. However, adding the `[Bind]` doesn't change anything and the nickname parameter is always `null`
Even if I'm not sure what you call "dynamic", my `modal` is "hard-coded" on the view and called by `$("#myModal").modal()` if necessary.
How can I "re-parse the validator" ?

Comment: If the controls for the modal exist when you first generate the view, then re-parsing the validator is not necessary (but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542509/validate-dynamically-added-fields/26542591#26542591) explains it).

Comment: I also suggest you look my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models/27517407#27517407) which is related and shows how you can modify the `jquery.validate.js` file to strip the prefix. I have seen some action on the bug report I made so hopefully this will be resolved in the next issue of `jquery`

Comment: And sorry, it needs to needs to be `[Bind(Prefix="MyOtherModel.Nickname")]`, not `[Bind(Prefix="MyOtherModel")]`. See update

Comment: Aaaaah, yes, it's better with `[Bind(Prefix="MyOtherModel.Nickname")]`, thanks a lot !