# Dynamically Added Input fields passed Validation and submit cannot to another page

Tags: php, dynamic, jquery-validate, submit-button

I 'm beginner, In dynamically added Input fields [Reference From: Validate Dynamically Added Input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536271/validate-dynamically-added-input-fields), when passed Validation and submit cannot to another page

Follow script sample.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var numberIncr = 1; // used to increment the name for the inputs

        function addInput() {
            $('#inputs').append($('<input class="comment" name="name'+numberIncr+'" />'));
            numberIncr++;
        }

        $('form.commentForm').on('submit', function(event) {

            // adding rules for inputs with class 'comment'
            $('input.comment').each(function() {
                $(this).rules("add", 
                    {
                        required: true
                    })
            });            

            // prevent default submit action         
            event.preventDefault();

            // test if form is valid 
            if($('form.commentForm').validate().form()) {
                console.log("validates");
            } else {
                console.log("does not validate");
            }
        })

        // set handler for addInput button click
        $("#addInput").on('click', addInput);

        // initialize the validator
        $('form.commentForm').validate();

   });


</script>
```

when passed validation click submit butt cannot to action="/action_page_post.php"

And HTML code

```
<form class="commentForm" method="get" action="/action_page_post.ph">
    <div>

        <p id="inputs">    
            <input class="comment" name="name0" />
        </p>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="button" value="add" id="addInput" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i think there is a problem with action....check your file name properly it will be action_page_post.php and not.ph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes I made**

- changed `on('submit')` to `submitbutton.onclick`
- added `$('.commentForm').submit();` inside the if condition which execute if the validation is true

Reason : Since you are using `event.preventDefault()`, it will prevent the default behaviour of the form and so did not go to next page. So You have to submit the form manually using `$(form).submit();`
The below code will work on normal page but not on *SO Snippet*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var numberIncr = 1; // used to increment the name for the inputs

        function addInput() {
            $('#inputs').append($('<input class="comment" name="name'+numberIncr+'" />'));
            numberIncr++;
        }

        $('input.submit').click(function(event) {
            // adding rules for inputs with class 'comment'
            $('input.comment').each(function() {
                $(this).rules("add", 
                    {
                        required: true
                    });
            });            

            // prevent default submit action         
            event.preventDefault();
            // test if form is valid 
            if($('form.commentForm').validate().form()) {
                console.log("validates");
                $('.commentForm').submit();
            } else {
                console.log("does not validate");
            }
        })

        // set handler for addInput button click
        $("#addInput").on('click', addInput);

        // initialize the validator
        $('form.commentForm').validate();
        

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="commentForm" method="get" action="action_page_post.php">
    <div>

        <p id="inputs">    
            <input type="text" class="comment" name="name0" />
        </p>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="button" value="add" id="addInput" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Ya. Thanks @Sparky, it was a typo. Corrected.