# how do i validate using java script in clone jquery controls have different id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how do i validate clone control using javascript
please answer me thank you in advance.

[please check this image i have to validate this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt0AH.png)
    
      
        
        
        
                          
          Course Name
          Topic Name
          Description
          Parent Topic Name
          Action

```
      <tr id="id" class="trrow">
        <td class="col-md-4">
          <select class="form-control select2 selectCourse" data-id="1" id="course_id_1" name="course_id[]" data-live-search="true" >
            <option value="" selected="selected"> Select Course Name</option>
            <?php
                  $sql = "SELECT * from course_master";
                  $result = $connect->query($sql);
                   while($row_pt = $result->fetch_array())
                                                         { 

                                                             ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_pt['course_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_pt['course_name']; ?></option>

                <? php 
                                                         }
            ?>
                             </select >
        </td>


        <td class="col-md-2"> <input class="form-control" id="topic_name1" name="topic_name[]" maxlength="250" value="" placeholder="Enter Topic Name" type="text"></td>

          <td class="col-md-4"><textarea class="form-control" style="resize: none;" id="topic_description1" name="topic_description[]" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea></td>

          <td class="col-md-2"><select class="form-control select2" id="parent_id_1" name="parent_id[]" data-live-search="true" ></select></td>

          <td class="col-md-2"><input type="button" name="add" value="Add Row" class="btn btn-success"></td>

                       </tr>  
                       </table>
                </div>

      <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-form-action btn-submit">Save</button>
      </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Where is the code, you have tried?

Comment: i don't have upload it here

Comment: give me advice how do i validate in clone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536271/validate-dynamically-added-input-fields