# Adding Validation to dynamic generated fields using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple dynamic fields generated on the page. I am trying to validate those fields using jquery validator plugin. I have used this code for validation and it is working, but there are some fields whose name i knew so i want other validation on that field whose name i know so how can i add that code here it can be select, or input box :

```
jQuery('form#add_form input').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).rules('add',{
            required: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: When you creating dynamic filed set one class each filed after that apply validation function

Comment: @jishan siddique: There can be multiple elements with the same name because some fields are array type

Comment: Can i use multiple add segments for inputs  so that i can pass input name and add apply the rule to that field

Comment: Yes you can add please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536271/validate-dynamically-added-input-fields